# Keydown from simulator

Tags: android

hi all i have a problem in my application please see the code below for reference. the problem that i am facing is that when i press keydown in textview from my simulater keyboard i want to uncheck my check box ..thank you in advance

```
   in main activity textbox is:
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox1);

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            checbox.setChecked(false);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys..

It's working

```
             @Override
             public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             switch (keyCode) {
                       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
                       checbox.setChecked(false);
                       return true;
                       default:
                       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D`, which is the key for letter 'D'.

What you want is probably `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you type any key in `EditText` (not `TextView`) you can use `TextWatcher`.

```
user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox1);

user.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
    {
        checbox.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```